Using Puphpeteer to scrape web page with no classes or ids
I'm helping a friend to migrate their blog from a "homemade" platform to Wordpress and the original developers have not been helpful in extracting the content so I'm trying to figure out how to scrape the site.  I'm using PHP & Puppeteer (PuPHPEteer).
https://www.conversationwithachef.com/
The home page has a "load more" button at the bottom to load more blog posts, which I need to "click" with the script. The button is not actually a button though, its a div (actually, a nested div - the outer div has the click action)
I tried using the script on this post here
$page->click("//div[contains(., 'Load More')]");

I get an error:

Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '//div[contains(., 'Load More')]' is not a valid selector.

I'm also not sure how to make it click the parent element with php?
If I try like this:
$lm_buttons = $page->querySelectorXpath("//div[contains(., 'Load More')]");
echo count($lm_buttons);

The result is 8 - I think because of all the nested divs?

If the button itself has a known text content, can't you use that?

My answer in that thread provides more options that let you be more precise than contains. I'm not familiar with the PHP Puppeteer API, but worst case scenario you can evaluate and loop over every element looking for one with a child node that equals the text you want--this would get the deepest element. Or, less reliably, just grab the tail of the 8 divs you retrieved here.
